# Why can't a SQL Server be tagged during the creation in Azure CLI?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-cli

According to the [docs for `az sql server create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/sql/server?view=azure-cli-latest#az-sql-server-create-examples), there's no way to specify the tags. I can also confirm it because running

```
az sql server create --resource-group groupy `
   --name sql-sqlserver-v12 `
   --admin-user hakuna --admin-password matata
```

works, while

```
az sql server create --resource-group groupy --name sql-sqlserver-v12 `
   --admin-user hakuna --admin-password matata `
   --tags some=thing
```

fails. It confuses me because it's generally possible to tag up other things during hte creation. Also, there's a field in the returned JSON called *tags* (being empty now). I also see that the GUI has a way spot to add tags.

What is the reason of such (to me) inconsistent syntax? Is there a reason not to tag up a server? If so, what? If not, how to tag it as per best-practices?

Comment: This doesn't feel like a question [so] can answer. Why Microsoft programmed their console application the way they did can only be answered by Microsoft. You'd be better off raising it on their services and perhaps asking for it as a feature request.

Comment: Already raised here https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/17052

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is hard to answer.

You can Tag via inherited tags, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/costs/enable-tag-inheritance or creation via Infrastructure as Code files (bicep/arm) which provide more consistency.